# Spy a method that has been called when onPress on an Alert

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a `removeService` method that gets called when `onPress` 'ing inside an Alert like this

```
Alert.alert(
      [...],
          onPress: () => removeService();
    );
  }
```

this is the test:

```
    const spyAlert = jest.spyOn(Alert, 
    "alert");
    const spyRemoveService = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Component removeService={spyRemoveService} />
    );

    wrapper
      .find("RemoveServiceButton")
      .props()
      .handleRemoveService();

    // Click onPress
    spyAlert.mock.calls[0][2][1].onPress();

    expect(spyRemoveService).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

However, when I run the test I get `TypeError: removeService is not a function`

why?

Comment: Is `removeService` working if you test it manually?

Comment: Yes, its working in the RN app

Comment: What's AddServiceProgressScreen? Please post all relevant code, not just pieces of it.

Comment: It's just the name of the component, the most important stuff is there: the spy, the method and the Alert. I have edited it.

Comment: Can you show more context around where `Alert.alert()` gets called?

Comment: The wrapper has a `RemoveServiceButton`, which has a prop called `handleRemoveService` that calls the alert

Comment: @estus is right, we can't see enough code to help.  Please post more context.  (specifically, `removeService` appears to be used as a local variable since it is not referencing `props` so how did it get assigned?)

Comment: @ismaeloliva The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which is required by SO rules. It is off-topic and can be closed. Please, post all code that is used in this test

Comment: Sorry guys! removeService comes from this.props, that is why I am passing it to the shallow function

Comment: Can you edit your component code? It's not clear